# Handling illegal character <0x1A> in database output

Tags: scala

I am working on a data transformation pipeline which reads data from an Oracle SQL relational DB, writes it to an RDF triplestore, and then pulls it into JVM memory. The original database contains some cells which have string values starting with the Unicode character sometimes represented as `<0x1a>` or `U+001A`. This is probably in the database by mistake, but I have no control over this database and have to deal with it as is. I also can't modify the strings, as they are later used as primary keys to lookup information from other tables in the database (yes, I understand this is not ideal). I am working on Windows.

The cells containing this character are mapped to literal values in the triplestore. When attempting to pull and iterate through the data from the triplestore, I receive the following error due to the presence of the illegal character:

```
error:org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException: 
org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.QueryEvaluationException: 
org.eclipse.rdf4j.query.resultio.QueryResultParseException: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1085; columnNumber: 14; An 
invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1a) was found in the element content of 
the document.
```

In case it's interesting, here's the code I'm using to iterate my results from the triplestore:

```
val cxn = getDatabaseConnection()
val query = getTriplestoreQuery()
val tupleQueryResult = cxn.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, query).evaluate()
// fails at this line when illegal XML character is discovered
while (tupleQueryResult.hasNext()) 
{
      // do some stuff with the data
}
```

I'm struggling a bit because I have to find a way to pull this data into memory without modifying the strings as they currently exist in the database. I haven't been able to find an escape solution for this case yet. My last resort would be to catch the QueryEvaluationException and simply not process the damaged strings, but it would be preferable to be able to salvage this data.

Comment: `query` is just a string, yes? Why can't you just do `query.replaceAll`?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik the issue is not in the query string. it is in the results that are returned from the query.